# Show logging output for failed testcases last in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am running pytest with the flags as such:
`pytest test/test_app.py -rA -l`

It shows logs for all cases, with the failed case logs first, meaning I have to **scroll through a ton of logs** to get to the top for the failed case logs.

Is there a way to **only show failed case logs**, or to **show failed cases last**, after the passed cases?

Comment: Have you tried rerunning with `pytest -lf`?

Comment: @Grismar i have found that `-rF` flag helps

Answer (score -1):

I have found a workflow that seems to work well for me. I am working on a **Mac** and using **Terminal**, so your hotkeys might be different.

1. Before running the test I clear the existing terminal with `Cmd+k`
2. Then I run my test, either with `-rF` or `-rA` depending on whether I want to see all logs or only failure cases

```sh
pytest test/test_app.py -rA -l
```

3. after the run completes, I go to the top of the result (since it shows failures first) with the **Home** hotkey, which is `Cmd+<up arrow>`. This is quite useful in Mac terminal because it highlights the command in bright yellow after jumping to Home or End(`Cmd+<down arrow>`).